# How to compare a column to a parameter in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oraclereports

my code goes like this..

```
SELECT ALL TBL_MONITOR.ITEM_ID, TBL_MONITOR.CATEGORY, 
TBL_MONITOR.BRANDNAME, TBL_MONITOR.PRICE, TBL_MONITOR.QUANTITY
FROM TBL_MONITOR
where 
case when :pricetag = 'Great' then tbl_monitor.price >= :para_price end,
case when :pricetag = 'Less' then tbl_monitor.price >= :para_price end
```

this part does not work, it says.. missing keyword ==> >= :para_price end

```
==> >= :para_price end,
```

wat i want to do is if the user input 'Greater' the reports will show prices greater than the ':para_price' 
how would i fix this? Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You can format source code with the `{}` toolbar button. I've done it for you this time. It also helps to provide all the relevant information you have: *does not work* is not a helpful description.

Comment: what do you mean _does not work_?

Comment: im sorry wahat i mean is.. the error is in that line,, it says.. missing keyword ==> >= :para_price end;

Comment: i am using Oracle 9i: Reports Builder.. :)

Comment: If you are learning Oracle, you should get used to the ORA-XXXXX error codes. They are vital for an Oracle developer since they explain the exact error condition. You can even Google for them. So don't ignore them.

Comment: @niktrs tanx but it still shows the same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try out this

```
WHERE 
(:pricetag = 'Great' AND tbl_monitor.price >= :para_price)
OR
(:pricetag = 'Less' AND tbl_monitor.price <= :para_price)
```

Comment: :) why so? What exactly does not work? Can you show a signature of stored procedure?

Comment: @user880267.  We are not telepathic.  "it doesn't work" does not provide nearly enough information.  Please describe the observed behaviour and how it differes from what you're expecting, including any error messages.   If you don't give us the details you won't get an answer.  Help us to help you.

Comment: im sorry wahat i mean is.. the error is in that line,, it says.. missing keyword ==> >= :para_price end; do i have to do something with the '>=' ??

Comment: 1) In code snippet I've privided no 'end' keyword, so you still using your original query?  2) Share SP signature

Comment: nope.. i tried this one but it did not retrieve data just a blank page.. hey wat do mean stored procedure? .. im just a beginner ;p wat im doing is just a simple report :))

Comment: :pricetag.. is that what u call SP? :)

Comment: No, SP is a Stored procedure, :pricetag is a variable

Comment: weew.. now it works haha.. sorry sir, i deleted all the parameters i made before then i make new ones.. and tadah!! THANK YOU so much :))

Answer (score 3):

The SQL `CASE` statement (apart from the syntax errors you are making) is not a flow control instruction like in C or PHP. It's an expression that **returns** a value and not a way to decide which part of your code will be executed.

You didn't care to say what you are trying to accomplish or how is it failing, but it looks like you want a simple expression:

```
WHERE (:pricetag = 'Great' AND tbl_monitor.price >= :para_price)
OR (:pricetag = 'Less' AND tbl_monitor.price <= :para_price)
```

Comment: hmm.. wats with the AND keyword? hmmm... the scenario is like this the user wanted the report to show 'Greater' values than he input in ':para_price'.. thats why i used case statement..

Comment: No, it uses different operator depends on value of pricetag

Comment: hey is it possible to use if then stmt in reports?

Comment: @domo: Have you actually tried our suggestions? How exactly do they fail to retrieve the exact rows you need? Could you provide a few sample rows where it fails?

Comment: weew.. now it works haha.. sorry sir, i deleted all the parameters i made before then i make new ones.. and tadah!! THANK YOU so much :))

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
SELECT ALL TBL_MONITOR.ITEM_ID, 
      TBL_MONITOR.CATEGORY, 
      TBL_MONITOR.BRANDNAME, 
      TBL_MONITOR.PRICE, 
      TBL_MONITOR.QUANTITY
FROM TBL_MONITOR
WHERE (:pricetag = 'Great' AND tbl_monitor.price >= :para_price)
OR (:pricetag = 'Less' AND tbl_monitor.price <= :para_price)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ALL TBL_MONITOR.ITEM_ID, TBL_MONITOR.CATEGORY, 
TBL_MONITOR.BRANDNAME, TBL_MONITOR.PRICE, TBL_MONITOR.QUANTITY
FROM TBL_MONITOR
where 
1 = CASE 
      WHEN :pricetag = 'Great' 
      AND  tbl_monitor.price >= :para_price
      THEN  1
      WHEN :pricetag = 'Less' 
      AND  tbl_monitor.price <= :para_price
      THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END
```

Comment: wats with the AND keyword? hmmm... the scenario is like this the user wanted the report to show 'Greater' values than he input in ':para_price'..

Comment: AND means that the both condition must be TRUE: **:pricetag = 'Great'** AND **tbl_monitor.price >= :para_price**

Comment: waoah.. wat i want to do is if the user input 'Graeter' the reports will show prices greater than the ':para_price'